# How to tell R to view observations of a different variable if a certain condition is met

Tags: r

I have a data frame put together from FRED data, I'm trying to find the proportion of times each variable has indicated a recession correctly.
I've mutated the data to give me a T/F output if each variable is indicating a recession.

How do I tell R to look at, for example, if the bondyieldTF is indicating a recession(TRUE), then look at RecessionTF variable to see if (say in the next 4 observations) RecessionTF returns TRUE?

I have yet try try anything because I don't know where to begin (what to look up) to solve my problem.

```
    bondyieldTF RecessionTF
   <lgl>       <lgl>      
 1 TRUE        FALSE      
 2 TRUE        FALSE      
 3 TRUE        FALSE      
 4 TRUE        TRUE       
 5 TRUE        TRUE       
 6 FALSE       TRUE       
 7 FALSE       TRUE       
 8 FALSE       TRUE       
 9 FALSE       TRUE       
10 FALSE       TRUE       
11 FALSE       FALSE
```

So what I want is to look at `bondyieldTF`, if in row 5, it is `TRUE` then look at `RecessionTF` Row 5,6,7,8, if any of those are `TRUE`, `bondyieldTF` was correct. If there are no true in `RecessionTF` Row 5,6,7,8, then `BondyieldTF` was incorrect.

```
EconFrame %>% 
  if (bondyieldTF == TRUE){
    if (RecessionTF == TRUE){
      
      Indication = Correct
    } else {
      Indication = Incorrect
    }
  }
```

This is the best I can come up with, and it says

Error in if (.) bondyieldTF == TRUE else { : the condition has length> 1

Comment: It almost always helps if you can include some example data (fine if it's fake) and an example of the sort of output you're expecting. I don't know what you mean by "telling R to view / look at" values. It sounds like you might be using `dplyr` since you mention `mutate`. Are you looking to add another indicator that, for instance, is TRUE if that row's `yield_curve_recession` is TRUE, and if any of the next 4 values of `Recession` are TRUE?

Comment: @JonSpring. That sounds like what I'm trying to do.
Right now I have: mutate(bondyieldTF = BondYield < 0), to output a T/F into bondyieldTF variable. So I want to be able to say, If bondyieldTF is TRUE, look at RecessionTF next 4 observations and if any are true in RecessionTF then bondyieldTF was correct(TRUE), if not then bondyieldTF was incorrect(FALSE).

Comment: Gnartank, it's generally preferred to put the sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`) and code attempted in your question in [code block]s. Could you [edit] your question and add it there? Some discussions about how to fill out the question to be as reproducible as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.